# Is there a way to encode an alternate root path in a URL?

Tags: html, path, root

I'm **assuming** that html pages essentially **extract a root** path by stripping the contents before the first single slash char.

Now Given that assumption, can we **tell an html page to use a different root?**  for example, if I have a proxy that is the root, and the proxy has a slash in it:

```
http://localhost:8080/proxy1/
```

which I want to use, rather than the normally computed root:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

Is there a way I can modify the way my page computes its own root? i.e.

```
http://localhost:8080/<ROOT=http://localhost:8080/proxy>
```

**note** the last url is of course, a totally made up construct to imagine/illustrate the end goal...

**IF** this is impossible, which I suspect it is, what is the more general way of dealing with a proxy that has slashes in it?

Comment: I noticed a vote to close.  Any particular reason ?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking some more about this, really there are a few ways to solve the problem addressed here.  Here are two:

**1) Give up on the complex proxy with multiple slashes in it, and just map your proxy to a domain name**

Since the "The forward slash (in an absolute url) is automatically replaced with the transfer protocol and domain name of the current website (from http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php?ref)", it will *just work* if your web app uses absolute urls properly.

**2) Embed a root URI in your application options**

This can be instrumented to tell a web server that "when you get requests to /, forward them to /x/y/z".  As an example, the prometheus monitoring system provides such an option so that the application can set the root for all requests dynamically.

...There are likely other valid solutions/answers/comments on this general problem as well.